# combined connection for 3 non-stable channels

Tags: linux, networking, connection, high-availability

I have 3 non-stable connections between 2 my Linux servers located in different countries.
These 3 connections have different routes. From time to time one or two connections have packet loss problem or even don't work at all, so I have 1 or 2 connections alive. Also there is a data exchange between the servers, so when connection issues happen I have to detect it in some way and send data using next channel.

Is there any software solution that can set up a virtual network using all the channels I have and automatically balance the data in the channels? May be some kind of multilink OpenVPN setup or virtual NIC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iptables can do this. Have a look at http://tetro.net/misc/multilink.html

Comment: this solution is great for home setup - so when the one interface is down it'll switch to the next one. But I mean the stuff which allow to eliminate packet loss problem i.e. interface is not down in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have used network bonding in the past for local networks.

Read the high availability section of [bonding](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding#Configuring_Bonding_for_High_Availability).

However I am not sure how this works with wan.